# Monitorar disco rigido Linux

Tags: linux, servidor, lado-do-servidor

Olá gostaria de saber se é possível executar uma determinada ação(executar um arquivo shell script por exemplo) quando o servidor ultrapassar uma determinada porcentagem de armazenamento.

*Comando utilizado para visualizar o espaço em disco do servidor:
df -h

Att,

Comment: Faça um cron job que executa um Shell Script utilizado para verificar o espaço em disco. Nesse shell script você pode executar algo (como mandar um email) dependendo do retorno do df -h. Seu cron job poderia ser configurado pra rodar a cada minuto (ou como você desejar).